# How can I setup peer-to-peer connections without using GKPeerPickerController?

Tags: ios, networking, p2p, gamekit

I want people to be able to start my iOS app on their device, and anyone nearby running my app (probably bluetooth only for now) would automatically connect with each other. I've read about and used GKPeerPickerController, but I don't want the user to have to think about which device they want to connect with.

I'm just not understanding how to handle the connectivity without using GKPeerPickerController.

I am targeting iOS 5.0 with this app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This page goes into more detail on how this is possible, although the focus is more on using just bluetooth: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40710-gamekit-api.html